# Slicing lists of Groovy objects

Tags: groovy

I have a Groovy object:

```
class Student {
    String fName
    String lName
    String email
    Date dob
    // ...etc.
}
```

I have a list of Students:

```
List<Student> allStudents = getSomehow()
```

I would like to create a list of their emails:

```
List<String> emails = []
allStudents.each { student ->
    emails << student.email
}
```

Is there a Groovier way to do this and get my email list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy with `collect()`.

```
def emails = allStudents.collect { it.email }
```